# overflow-x is making p tag data out of the box in card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is the html and css code to make elemts put ina scroll manner where there are multiple such listings on my page .
Currently the problem is the p data tag goes out of the whole div element when i apply the overflow-x element .i have created a div element in which i have added the p tag and image tag and have given the overflow property to the div class

```
  <div class="container-fluid scrollmenu">
      <div class="row text-centre">
        <div class="scroll-data">

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img class="d-block w-100 card-img-top" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
               Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="./Images/banner-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
           Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    Css

    .container-fluid .row .scroll-data { 
        overflow-x:auto; 
        white-space: nowrap; 
        display: flex;


    } 

    .container-fluid .row .scroll-data .col-xs-4 p
    {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        color: blueviolet;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `white-space: nowrap` on the container? That is causing your text to not wrap. Remove that and it should work.

```
.container-fluid .row .scroll-data { 
    overflow-x:auto;  
    display: flex;
}
```